# Abaqus scripting issue

Tags: python, scripting, surface, abaqus

I am new to the forum. I have just recently started building python scripts to run into Abaqus and have a basic question to solve the problem I'm having. I am currently trying to do a simulation. I am modeling heat flow through a pipe thickness but I am having a hard time defining a surface to which I want to apply my constant temperature BC. I am attempting to apply Temp BC to the pipe surface but am not able to capture the surface properly I think. I am using the following script. I am getting an error message 'Set must contain some entities' at the last line in the script below when I run it into Abaqus. Appreciate your time. Thanks a lot!

```
internal_radius= 0.1
length_pipe= 1.0

internalPipePoint = (0.1, 0.0, 0.5)
internalPipe = myInstance.faces.findAt((internalPipePoint,))
intDiaRegion = regionToolset.Region(side1Faces=internalPipe)
myModel.TemperatureBC(name='Temp Int',createStepName='temp', region=intDiaRegion, magnitude=100.0)
```

Also, when trying to print 'internalPipe' and 'intDiaRegion' in the abaqus I am getting this output.

```
internalPipe: (mdb.models['Pipe'].rootAssembly.instances['pipeInstance'].faces.findAt(((0.1, 0.0, 0.5),)))
intDiaRegion: (Region(side1Faces=mdb.models['Pipe'].rootAssembly.instances['pipeInstance'].faces.findAt(((0.099154, 0.012978, 0.666667),),)))
```

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to work with `findAt(...)`, try doing the same with either `getByBoundingBox(...)` or `getByBoundingCylinder(...)`. I'd also recommend you to create a `Set` using the selected faces (`internalPipe`) for verification in the CAE.

Comment: Hi @Anbu, Thank you very much for your answer. I tried using both 'getByBoundingBox' and 'getByBoundingCylinder' but neither worked. It still gives the same error at the same point, i.e, 'Set must contain some entities'.

Comment: Upon printing 'internalPipe' and 'intDiaRegion' it gives the following output.  For getByBoundingCylinder:  ('InternalPipe:', mdb.models['Pipe'].parts['Part Pipe'].faces.findAt(((-0.149089, -0.01651, 0.333333),),((0.099154, 0.012978, 0.666667),),((-0.066705, -0.113371, 1.0),),((-0.066705, 0.113371, 0.0),),))
('IntDiaRegion:', Region(side1Faces=mdb.models['Pipe'].parts['Part Pipe'].faces.findAt(((-0.149089, -0.01651, 0.333333),),((0.099154, 0.012978, 0.666667),),((-0.066705, -0.113371, 1.0),),((-0.066705, 0.113371, 0.0),),)))

Comment: And for getByBoundingBox: ('InternalPipe:', ())
('IntDiaRegion:', Region(side1Faces=))

Comment: @Anbu thanks very much for the suggestion to create `Set` for the surface definition. It seems to be working for me.